# Recoloring a set of PNG icons

Tags: css, imagemagick, image-manipulation, glyphicons

I have a set of icons in a .png format. The customer wants them in a different colour. I know they are from either glyphicons or fontawesome icon fonts, but I do not know how they were generated. I tried this command to recolour them, but bits of red are always left behind and increasing fuzz value has negative effects on other parts of image:

```
mogrify -fuzz 41% -fill "#5DBFAD" -opaque "#ea5648" *icon.png *arrow.png *rtl.png
```

Image before:
[image: Image before]

Image after:
[image: Image after]

Note: Look closely if you have a dark theme on, there is a second dark-grey icon over the coloured one.

I need either a way to get rid of these red artefacts or a way to generate these icons on my own with the colour of my choice (a full replacement in css is also an option, using the icon font, colouring it and animating). Also for an unknown reason some icons have the coloured one on top like this:

[image: Coloured icon on top]

Extra info: When hovered-over these icons transition a few pixels up/down to show the other icon. This is a part of a free nopCommerce theme: http://themes.nopaccelerate.com/themes/nopaccelerate-simplex-theme-3/?utm_source=nop&utm_medium=extension&utm_campaign=extension-directory

Comment: It would seem more reliable to find the original icon, recolor it and save as a png (if that's the easiest route rather than recode to use icons direct). Something like fa2png?

Comment: @AHaworth It is possible, though I do not know any tool that would generate this over-under formation and I am sure as hell not doing it by hand. I have actually solved this by making my own re-colouring program for now, but I am still looking for better ways for the future

Comment: See my ImageMagick script, huemap, at my web site http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick. Perhaps that will do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ImageMagick to re-color just the bottom half of your input image with a command like this...

```
magick input.png -crop 1x2@ ^
   ( +clone -fill "#5DBFAD" -colorize 100 ) -delete 1 -append result.png
```

That isolates just the bottom half inside the parentheses, and uses "-colorize" to re-color the image without leaving the artifacts. Then it re-assembles the halves to complete the icon.

Unfortunately "-clone" is not an available option to "mogrify", so for a command like this you'd need to use just "magick" and a "for" loop in your command shell to process multiple images.

The command is in Windows syntax. For a *nix system change the continued-line caret "^" to a backslash "\" and escape the parentheses with backslashes "\(...\)".

Regarding the icons with the colored part on top instead of the bottom, ImageMagick can probably determine which end is colored, but it could get complicated. Maybe easier to sort them manually and process them in two groups. To color just the top half, add "-rotate 180" just after reading in the image and "-rotate 180" again before writing the result.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Best way is ask support team for this
As you using nopAccelerate's theme you can direct reach them at support(at)nopaccelerate.com or go to [here](https://www.nopaccelerate.com/wiki/support/) and create support ticket with them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a simple program to do this, so I am posting the source here, but the [@GeeMack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8174768/geemack)'s answer seems like a more elegant solution so I am accepting it.

My source code:
Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace ColorReplacer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Supplied path: {args[0]}, from color: {args[1]} to color: {args[2]}");

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open);
            var image = new Bitmap(fs);
            fs.Close();

            for (var i = 0; i < image.Width; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < image.Height; j++)
                {
                    var pixel = image.GetPixel(i, j);
                    if (pixel.R == ColorConverter.RfromHex(args[1]) && pixel.G == ColorConverter.GfromHex(args[1]) && pixel.B == ColorConverter.BfromHex(args[1]))
                    {
                        image.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(pixel.A, ColorConverter.RfromHex(args[2]), ColorConverter.GfromHex(args[2]), ColorConverter.BfromHex(args[2])));
                    }
                }
            }

            image.Save(args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

ColorConverter.cs

```
using System.Globalization;

namespace ColorReplacer
{
    public static class ColorConverter
    {
        public static int RfromHex(string color)
        {
            if (color.IndexOf('#') != -1)
                color = color.Replace("#", "");

            return int.Parse(color.Substring(0, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        }

        public static int GfromHex(string color)
        {
            if (color.IndexOf('#') != -1)
                color = color.Replace("#", "");

            return int.Parse(color.Substring(2, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        }

        public static int BfromHex(string color)
        {
            if (color.IndexOf('#') != -1)
                color = color.Replace("#", "");

            return int.Parse(color.Substring(4, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        }
    }
}
```